# truststore.jks can not be found when run Spring boot kafka app using java -jar

Tags: spring, ssl, apache-kafka, executable-jar

My app can be run in eclipse or via **gradlew bootRun**. But when I build a 'fat' jar file app.jar via **gradlew build**, and then start app via **java -jar** app.jar, I get below error:

ERROR o.a.k.c.s.ssl.SslEngineBuilder - Modification time of key store could not be obtained: kafka_truststore.jks
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: kafka_truststore.jks

The kafka_truststore.jks is defined in application.properties like this

kafka.truststore_location=src/main/resources/kafka_truststore.jks

It is used in kafka client config class like below

@Value("${kafka.truststore_location}")
private String trustStoreLocation;

props.put("ssl.truststore.location", trustStoreLocation);

Dose any one know how to resolve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you build the jar, all the files from resources usually get packed at the project root.

so in order to get the trustore,jks working, change your application.propeties as below

```
kafka.truststore_location=classpath:kafka_truststore.jks
```

This will work from IDE and when you run the fat jar independently.

Comment: Thanks Vishnu. Actually I had tried to set location to classpath:kafka_truststore.jks. But I got org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer.

Comment: do you have more info about the exception?  if classpath doesnt work then you can store the file at some path for eg: /tmp/kafka_truststore.jks  (unix system).
and in property file try as below 
`kafka.truststore_location=file:/tmp/kafka_truststore.jks`

Comment: file:/ doesn't work either. I have following workaround.

Comment: 1. unpack the fat jar. 2. copy keystores to project root directory. 3. change app.properties as: kafka.trustore_location=kafka_truststore.jks. 4. run app using "java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"

Answer (score 0):

Solved !!
you can just copy the java `jdk` filr to `/tmp` folder and it works !!

```
cp /usr/lib/jvm/<your-jdk-package>/jre/lib/security/cacerts /tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```

In my case, it is:

```
cp /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/cacerts /tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks
```